# Date Validation in Apex programming

Tags: validation, date

I need to check that the user has given a valid date in a text box. For example if user enters 2014-02-29 it should throw an error saying it is not a valid date. I can use Date datatype but my requirement is that i need to use text box because in some condition it need to get data value and in some condition it need to get string value.

Thanks
IRaj

Answer (score 3):

There was another user looking to do the same thing on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834873/salesforce-apex-validating-date-for-format-and-value). He ended up solving his own question:

> So I used a regex to validate the format of the date being entered to
>   ensure it is in yyyy-MM-dd format.
>
> The I used Date.valueOf This built in method always takes a date in
>   the form of yyyy-MM-dd. It throws an exception if that has a bad value
>   like 9999-99-99 etc....I display the exception's message to the user
>   using e.getMessage() to complete my validation of the date fields.

Comment: Hi Jenny, Its working for me but Im not getting any error. Im getting next valid date. With some if conditions i am able to get my answer. Thanks for the help.